# How to pass a class as a type in a function

Tags: c++, class, constructor, relationship, function-parameter

I'm not entirely sure on the wording of my situation which makes it difficult to find the answer. Basically if there is a class A that has a private member which is of another class B (has-a relationship), how do I go about making Class A's constructor?

Class A constructor:

```
classA::classA(int a, int b, classB c);
```

this gives me "error: no matching function for call to 'classB::classB()' and then lists candidates based on their arguments and how many I provided; also of course 'expected primary function before c.' I'm probably missing something quite large which is why the code is very general so I only need a general answer to point me in the right direction. You can assume the rest of the code for B and A to be as minimal as possible. Thanks!

Comment: It would be helpful if you could also add the constructor's code. Anyway, it seems as if the constructor of A is trying to initialize it's B member with a constructor which takes no parameters, while the latter doesn't have one.

Comment: Not enough context. The single colon in classA:classA is suspicious. Is this a label for goto?

Comment: It would improve your question to show the code involved. [See here for posting guidelines](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

As I understand, you have a private member B within class A you don't initialize in the initialization list of your constructor. As a result, default constructor of B is called, which as the error suggest is not available.

```
class A {
    B b;
public:
    A(/* parameters */)
    : b(/* parameters to construct b */) // missing part
    { }
};
```